# Python - convert pgqueryobject to string

Tags: python, python-2.7, postgresql, pygresql

**Prelude:** 
Python version: 2.7.9
Pygresql version: 4.0

**Problem:** 
I am trying to check if a sub string exists within a `pgqueryobject` using python.

Basically I have this in terms of code:

```
import pg
con = pg.connect(...)
q = con.query(...)
```

Where `q` is a `pgqueryobject` returned from the `con.query(...)`

Calling `print(q)` prints the entire table however converting `q` to a `string` such as:

```
string = str(q)
print(string)
```

Prints `"<pg query result>"`.

I am trying to see if table has now instances (rows) which I planned on doing by converting the table to a string and searching for `"0 rows"` but I can't seem to figure out how to convert it to a string.

Is there I way I can go about doing this?

Comment: You can most likely accomplish this by saving the output of q.getresult() into a variable and then casting it into a string.
http://www.pygresql.org/contents/pg/query.html#pg.Query.getresult

Comment: Glad that helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can most likely accomplish this by saving the output of `q.getresult()` into a variable and then casting it into a string.

http://www.pygresql.org/contents/pg/query.html#pg.Query.getresult